# Computing the line integral using stokes theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Question** $\oint_C \mathbf{F}\bullet d\mathbf{r}$ where $$\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)=(y+z,z+x,x+y)$$
where C is the intersection of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 2y$ and the plane $y = z$

**My attempt:**

Am I correct in saying the answer is 0 because the Curl of F is (0,0,0)? Hence by stokes theorem this is 0?

Comment: Have you calculated the curl? And please check your equations $x2+y2=2y$ seems to be wrong.

Comment: Yes I have calculated the curl and I got 0, also why does it seem wrong?

Comment: Btw the curl is not a scalar. You should say that it is equal to the zero vector. You should check the conditions for the stokes theorem. If your conditions are meet you can conclude how you did.

Comment: Sorry yes that is what I meant. Also how would I go about showing the conditions? It is clear that F is a smooth vector field

Comment: It is also important that the surface that you are looking at is smooth (no corners). But if both conditions are meet you can conclude like you did :).